# Use variable outside of ajax success function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a set of time out functions inside one function

```
function myFunction()
{
   var data;

   setTimeout(function(){
       $.ajax({
         //My Ajax Junk
         success: function(data) {
            var data = data.trim();
            // I want to be able to use this later on.
         }
       }):
   }, 6000);

   setTimeout(function(){
      var shipping = 'f_name='+f_name+data;
      // Append data from previous call to shipping
   }, 12000);
}
```

I'm wanting to retrieve the data from the ajax success function and then use it inside the next timeout function by appending it to the shipping variable. I have declared the variable data outside of all the functions and then tried to add the success data to it. When I alert out the shipping variable it doesn't show anything extra (what the data should be adding).

The data is returning because I can see it in Google Chromes Network Tab.

How can I set a variable to be used throughout the entire function!?!?!?!?

Thank you in advance.

Also, the success function is returning prior to the call for the data to be added because of the timeout functions. I played with them to be set right for this instance.

Comment: You should have a read of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another name for the global variable like `global_data` and in the ajax assign the data value using `global_data = data.trim()`

Comment: I still need to wait 6 minutes before accepting answers although, this is the one I'm accepting. Once you think about it, it makes sense! Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

As a bad way: up your `var data;` and change `var data = data.trim();` to `tdata = data.trim();` from the function:

```
var tdata;
function myFunction(){

    setTimeout(function(){
       $.ajax({
         //My Ajax Junk
         success: function(data) {
            tdata = data.trim();
            // I want to be able to use this later on.
         }
       }):
    }, 6000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        var shipping = 'f_name='+f_name+tdata;
        // Append data from previous call to shipping
       }, 12000);
```

}

Comment: You need to change the variable name. Data is used as the argument name of the success function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction()
{
   var data;

   setTimeout(function(){
       $.ajax({
         //My Ajax Junk
         success: function(resp) {
            data = resp.trim(); // Dont declare it inside
            // I want to be able to use this later on.
         }
       }):
   }, 6000);

   setTimeout(function(){
      var shipping = 'f_name='+f_name+data;
      // Append data from previous call to shipping
   }, 12000);
}
```